# How do i send an email from a workflow with the whole list item as a attachment?

Tags: list, item

I am a newbie in sharepoint.
Our company has a email address that functions as a archive, I want to send a email from a workflow on a list item with the whole item as a attachment or in the email. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the link to display or edit form of that item in your email. This way all the details will be stored in SharePoint and all that they have to do is click on that link to view the item.

Answer (score 0):

If it were sufficient to only keep track of all the changes, you could set up an alert for modifications, sent to that archive mailbox.

If it needs to contain the whole "listitem" respectively all fields values, you can do that with a workflow. This should be feasible with a regular SharePoint designer workflow. If you need this for only a specific list, with a fixed set of fields (that do not change much), you can then retrieve each field value that you need in your workflow and concatenate them to an Email text, that then is sent from the workflow to that mailbox. If it needs to be more dynamic (for multiple list with different, changing sets of fields) it gets more tricky....

And if I understood your requirements (=> archive), the link to the listitem won't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use InfoPath, then there is feature to send email with screenshot of current form.